# When using UIImagePickerController, why would both the original and edited image be nil?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm looking at crash reports for one of my apps, and I see a crash in `imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)` that could only occur if both `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage` and `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` are nil.

This particular scenario has never occurred in testing, so I can't be sure why it's happening a handful of times in the wild. I've definitely seen situations where one or the other is nil, but never both.

Is there ever a situation where `didFinishPickingMedia` would get called with no actual image in the `info` dictionary?

Comment: Could it be that the selected media is a video and not an image?

Comment: Good point, but I don't think so - the first line in the function is a guard ensuring that `UIImagePickerControllerMediaType` is `kUTTypeImage`

Comment: Have you tested a scenario in which the image is stored in iCloud and not locally?

Comment: @ArikSegal Yes, I tested a shared album and `OriginalImage` was still populated.